# Dr Aphorism's advice

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, visual, chemistry

My old science teacher Dr Aphorism was brilliant – not just at teaching (and, of course, science), but also at providing invaluable life advice.  I always remember one day when I went to her office to talk about a coursework experiment that was not going well.  She sat me down, looked at my equations, and pointed at a term involving a square root.

"I know that's the part that's wrong," I said, "but I’ve tried everything, and it just doesn’t work out."

With that, Dr Aphorism smiled and directed my attention to a poster on her wall showing a modified Periodic Table.

"I’m going to leave you here for ten minutes," she said kindly, "and I want you to focus really hard on working out the meaning behind this poster.  When I come back I’m sure you’ll have a better understanding..."

**TASK: What is the hidden meaning behind this poster? The (perhaps ironic) correct answer is an 8-word phrase which can be enumerated as (5, ?, 7, ?, 4, ?, 3, ?), where some word lengths have been left unknown…**

[image]
<sup>*A colour guide for colour-blind solvers is available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYpgw.png).*</sup>

Comment: Gurer vf n pyrne cnggrea urer. Rnpu ryrzrag qvssref sebz gurve bevtvany ngbzvp ahzoref ol $\pm 1\pm 2\pm 3\pm 4\pm 6\pm 7\pm 10\pm 20\pm 30 \pm 80$ naq gurer vf ng yrnfg bar grez va rnpu pbybe gnxra frcnengryl jubfr qvssrerapr vf n zhygvcyr bs $10$

Comment: Nice attention to detail with the thumbtacks in the corners.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of it too. I have not completed it.

Comment: I have to get to work (an hour later than normal...thanks Stiv :-), but I noticed rot13(sbe rirel funqrq ryrzrag, gur nygrerq ngbzvp ahzore ersref gb na ryrzrag jubfr ngbzvp flzoby funerf n yrggre jvgu gur ngbzvp flzoby va gur funqrq fdhner. V gevrq uvggvat gur erfhygvat yrggref (obgu funerq naq abg-funerq, jvgu frireny pbzovangvbaf gurerbs) jvgu inevbhf Pnrfne naq Ivtarer pvcuref, ohg ab yhpx lrg.)

Comment: @JeremyDover I suggest you take a long lunch break to take your progress further ;-) Note that I don't tend to use ciphers like Vigenère without clue-ing it directly. You're looking for something that the character in the story could solve in 10 minutes, in someone else's office, without access to any complex code-solving tools - bear that in mind...

Comment: So I know the phrase is rot13(bsgra n ceboyrz unf zber guna bar fbyhgvba), but I'm not sure yet of the logic to get there. Hoping the wife doesn't make me start painting the bedroom before I finish.

Comment: @JeremyDover Nice work! There's a built-in ordering mechanism to the solution - spot that and you're done...

Comment: @Stiv: Even thought I didn't get the checkmark, I absolutely loved this puzzle, and really appreciate the craft you put into it. Wish I could upvote multiple times :-)

Comment: @JeremyDover Thanks, I'm glad to hear it :) It was born out of a sudden idea of "would *this* be possible...?" so I spent some time working out all the possible combinations that could be used, then had to devise a sentence that could be built out of them - and I was very chuffed it all worked out! Making the image in Excel was fun - plus now I have a template for future chemistry puzzles! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, notice that:

> The numbers of colored elements are a bit off.

But if we take a look further:

> The numbers are denoting other elements, which surprisingly share a common letter with the colored ones!

For example, for the RED one:

> - **Ni** is numbered 22, denoting **Ti**.
>  - **Ir** is numbered 87, denoting **Fr**.
>  - **Rg** is numbered 118, denoting **Og**.
>  - **Cf** is numbered 58, denoting **Ce**.

But, cleverly, we don't stop here! Taking a look far further:

> The numbers apparently share a common digit too!

For example, for the RED one:

> - Ni is numbered **22**, it should be **28**.
>  - Ir is numbered **87**, it should be **77**.
>  - Rg is numbered **118**, it should be **111**.
>  - Cf is numbered **58**, it should be **98**.

So if we tabulate the results, and taking the "differences":

> [image]

The last thing is to extract the final answer:

> For each group, sort the digit differences, then pick the letter differences.

The final answer is:

> **OFTEN A PROBLEM HAS MORE THAN ONE SOLUTION**.

Final remark (helped by the author):

> So the wise word from Dr Aphorism to be "Remember that often a problem has more than one solution". If the narrator insists to correct the single mistake in his/her square root part, it indeed may be hard to solve or even impossible: instead, try to look at another angle!
>
>  Perhaps there are more than a single mistake here? Perhaps there is another way to solve the problem? [@Johnson](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/63540/johnson) notices that square root may result not only positive but also negative solution (as many people forget!)
>
>  As illustrated in the poster (i.e. "there are not 1 but 2 mistakes" or "there are are not 1 but 2 solutions") surely Dr Aphorism knows how to teach her students a way of life! :)

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see the rot13(qvtvgf)! Nice job!

Comment: @JeremyDover whoops, sorry if I'm sniping, I just realized that you've already covered most of these in the comments ><

Comment: Congrats athin, you've found the answer :) For completeness, could you remark on why this might be helpful to the narrator's maths problem? Thanks. You might also like (but don't have) to explain explicitly that in this puzzle, rot13(rnpu pbybherq ryrzrag vf bhg ol bar qvtvg/punenpgre sebz n erny purzvpny ryrzrag - v.r. vs nffhzvat gurer vf n fvatyr zvfgnxr naq gelvat gb jbex bhg juvpu ryrzrag vg fubhyq or, gurer vf *zber guna bar fbyhgvba*...) +1

Comment: @athin: No sniping at all...you got it all the way there, and I didn't. I like to think I can appreciate your solution all the more because I know most of what went into it first-hand :-) Great work!

Comment: @Stiv added! hopefully it captured the final message, very nice puzzle indeed! :D

Comment: The final answer, combined with the square root, immediately made me think of the fact that rot13(Nal cbfvgvir ahzore k jvyy unir gjb fdhner ebbgf - (cbfvgvir naq artngvir). Gur cbfvgvir ebbg vf gur bar jr hfhnyyl guvax bs, ohg creuncf gur cebs vf erzvaqvat gur fghqrag gung nabgure bar lrg rkvfgf.)

Comment: @Johnson dang that's legit! Adding that :)

Comment: To make it more precise, a square root always results in a positive number. However, when it is part of a solution to a quadratic equation, there could be two solutions: one with is the square root,and another is the negative of the square root.

Comment: And that's a wrap! Thanks athin (and well done @Johnson - exactly the angle I was going for...). Checkmark awarded :)